# Parse namespace from xml tag using etree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

What is the best way to parse the namespace from the xml tag?  For example:

```
<test xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
    <xsd:step name="testing"/>
</test>
```

Printing out the .tag using xml.etree will be:

```
{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#}step
```

My goal is to just get the tag as "step"  I know I could just remove everything in {}, but I was wondering if there is a built in command that separates the namespace and tag.  If there is not a built in command, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no built-in functionality in either `xml` or `lxml` to achieve what you are looking for. Just remove the portion in brackets with a regex:

```
import re
re.sub('{.*}', '', tag)
```